# Codemagic with Gitlab Community Edition webhooks

Tags: flutter, gitlab, continuous-integration, webhooks, codemagic

I have connected Codemagic with a custom Gitlab Community edition repository. I created and configured the webhook as requested, but the pipeline is never triggered automatically when something on the repository is changed. Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Codemagic you can go to App Settings > Webhooks to check GitLab requests and results. This should help to understand why builds not triggered

Comment: There is not much info there, also this is not set up on Codemagic like a Gitlab repository, but as an Other/Custom repository.

Comment: what do you mean not much info? can you see incoming requests? if not, maybe app id is wrong?

Comment: It's just saying: No deliveries yet, as you can see on the screenshot, there are no incoming requests. The app id is correct.

Comment: is it possible to check if GitLab sends any requests on commit push? on GitHub there is a tab with recent deliveries for example

Comment: I was able to check your app id and can confirm that there is no logs with incoming requests. Also your server IP addresses are not blacklisted. So it means GitLab doesn't attempt to send any webhooks - maybe some issue with local firewall? or you simple didn't push any commits ‍♂️;)

Comment: How you checked my app id when I hided it?

Comment: there is the app name on the screenshot

Comment: I pushed a lot of commits.

Comment: Mikhail Tokarev Do you have some other advice, on what to try, because I'm pretty stuck here :( ?